# Xamarin Android: How to hide a item from mainactivity when a i click on recyclerview item

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Hello Everyon my name is Taniguchi

I've implemented a  botton navigation view on my mainactivity page, and i have a recyclerview, i would like to know, how can i hide this botton navigation view that is on myactivity page when i click on a item in the recyclerview.

My mainactivity class:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    public int position;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private List<Email> mEmails;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerViwer);
        mRecyclerView.AddItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.Context, DividerItemDecoration.Vertical));
        mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
        SetupList();


        //Create our layout Manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails, this);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

       BottomNavigationView bottonButton = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
        RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
        bottonButton.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;


    }
```

My  recyclerview click listener:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView mName;
        public TextView mSubject;
        public TextView mMessage;
        public CheckBox cbx;
        public Button bottonbutton;
        public int count = 0;
        private Action<object, View.LongClickEventArgs, int> onLongClick;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {

            mName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            mSubject = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            mMessage = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            cbx = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        }
    }
```

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
    {
        private View view;
        private Boolean isSelected = false;

        public Boolean IsSelected()
        {
            return isSelected;
        }

        public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
        {
            isSelected = selected;
        }
        private Activity mActivity;
        private MyActionMode mActionMode;
        private List<Email> mEmails;
        private Context context;
        private ActionMode mode;
        public bool count = false;
        public int CountAuxiliar = 0;
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
        public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Context context)
        {
            mEmails = emails;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public RecyclerAdapter(List<Email> emails, Activity activity)
        {
            mEmails = emails;
            mActivity = activity;
        }
        public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public View mMainView { get; set; }
            public TextView mName { get; set; }
            public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
            public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

            public MyView(View view) : base(view)
            {
                mMainView = view;
            }

        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mEmails.Count; }
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
            View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder vh = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
            return vh;
        }
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {  
            RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
            myHolder.cbx.Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;

            myHolder.cbx.Checked = mEmails[position].IsSelected();
            myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
            myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[position].Subject;
            myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[position].Message;
            myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            myHolder.ItemView.Tag = position;
            myHolder.ItemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
            myHolder.ItemView.SetOnLongClickListener(this);
        }



        void View.IOnClickListener.OnClick(View v)
        {
            if (CountAuxiliar > 0 && mode != null)
            {
                int position = (int)v.Tag;
                mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
                v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
                v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
                if (mEmails[position].IsSelected())
                {
                    CountAuxiliar++;
                }
                else
                {
                    CountAuxiliar--;
                }
                mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionados";
                Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Click : " + CountAuxiliar + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            if (CountAuxiliar < 1 && count == true)
            {
                mode.Finish();
            }
        }

        public bool OnLongClick(View v)
        {

            if (CountAuxiliar < 1)
            {
                CountAuxiliar = 1;
                count = true;
                int position = (int)v.Tag;
                mEmails[position].setSelected(!mEmails[position].IsSelected());
                v.SetBackgroundColor(mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
```

BottomNavigationView bottonButton = FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
                    v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Visibility = mEmails[position].IsSelected() ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
                    mActionMode = new MyActionMode(mActivity, this, position);
                    v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation).Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    mode = mActivity.StartActionMode(mActionMode);
                    mode.Title = CountAuxiliar.ToString() + " " + "Selecionado";
                    count = true;

```
                Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Long Click : " + mEmails[position].IsSelected() + "---" + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

My Contextual Action Bar Class:

```
 public class MyActionMode : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
    {

        private RecyclerViewHolder holder;
        private Context mContext;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
        private int currentPosition;
        private Button button;
        public View v;
        private IMenu menu;
        private View menuItemView;
        private List<Email> mEmails;

        public MyActionMode(Context context) : this(context, null, 0)
        {

        }

        public MyActionMode(Context context, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, int position)
        {
            mContext = context;
            mAdapter = adapter;
            currentPosition = position;
        }

        public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
        {

            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.itemOneId:
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.itemTwoId:
                    // do Update
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
        {
            mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);
            button = (Button)menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.itemTwoId).ActionView;
            button.Background = null;
            var draw = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(mContext, Resource.Drawable.three_dots);
            button.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(draw, null, null, null);
            //button.Text = "";
            button.Click += delegate {
                PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(mContext, button);
                menu1.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
                menu1.Show();
            };

            return true;
        }

        public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
        {
            mode.Dispose();
        }

        public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

The error is ocorring in the following line of onlongclik function in recyclerview adapter:

```
BottomNavigationView bottonButton = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
```

The error is:
    CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Activity.FindViewById(int)'

And When i Try the following line:

```
  BottomNavigationView bottonButton = v.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
                bottonButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

The Error is:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I guess that you want to add BottomNavigationView, you want to click Recycler item to hide BottomNavigationView, am I right?

Firstly, you add BottomNavigationView, then create static bottomnavigationview1

```
public static  BottomNavigationView bottomnavigationview1;
```

then, change bottomnavigationview1 visibility in OnItemclick:

```
void OnClick (int position)
    {
        if (ItemClick != null)
            ItemClick (this, position);
        if (MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
        else
        {
            MainActivity.bottomnavigationview1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
    }
```

If yes, I do one sample that you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/Recycler

I just upload Mainactivity, main.xaml, and bottom_navigation_main.xml in github, please modify your project according to my file.

Here is the screenshot, when you click Recycler item, BottomNavigationView visibility will be changed.

[image]